# What is the cleanest way to define variables like this?

Tags: php, variables, coding-style

I have a variable:

```
$FolderName = date('c', time()); // I know time() is optional.. not the point.
```

Since I might be using this script I'm writing on a Windows machine and there are colons in the output, I'll need to do:

```
$FolderName = str_replace(':', '-', date('c', time()));
```

I feel like having too many functions within functions is sloppy.  What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Your approach is correct. :). Do it in same way.

Comment: Why exactly is using functions within function parameters sloppy? What you're doing now is not only easy to read... it's common practice! In simple cases, it far outweighs having to set and unset temporary variables or write niche functions that wont be used again.

Comment: Or. create a function like: `makeFolder(param)` and in that function you can have the above logic. At least when you make folders your code will be a bit easier to read and only your one function will be "messy". Then it can just be `$FolderName = makeFolder(time())` or whatever you may want to pass in to define the folder.

If there is every a bit of code that I have to write over and over, I almost always just toss it in a function.

Answer (score 1):

To make your folder name completely safe from a windows machine, you should do the following

```
$match = preg_match('/[\/|\\\|\?|"|\<|\>|\||\:|\*|%|\#]/is', $FolderName);
if($match)
{
  echo "Invalid filename. A filename can't contain any of the following characters: \ / : * ? \" < > | % # ";
}
else
{
  // do stuff..
}
```

All the above characters are invalid in a windows file name